# How to merge multiple code coverage file generated by vstest.exe using Jenkins or Fake scripts F#?

Tags: jenkins, f#, code-coverage

Unit test is generating multiple coverage files. I want all of them to be merged so that they can be converted and viewed in single html document.

Want to do it using some command line.

Comment: Have you tried googling it?

Answer (score 2):

Try [ReportGenerator](https://github.com/danielpalme/ReportGenerator) it's available as a [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ReportGenerator) package.

```
ReportGenerator converts XML reports generated by OpenCover, 
PartCover, Visual Studio or NCover into human readable reports 
in various formats.
```